# Why is my prediction from an LSTM network out of scale?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I've got some timer series data, and I've trained an lstm network to try and predict if the next item in the series is higher, the same or lower than the last item. For this I've created my train_x and train_y and set the first to the series data and the y to 0, 0.5 or 1.

Should I not expect values of exactly 0, 0.5 or 1? Should I inverse scale it? Or is there some way of working out which it should be?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why did you not model this as a classification problem?

Comment: Interesting, I had not considered that. I assume the lstm the way I have modeled it won't work for classification?